# Equivalent of real-time disk usage feature of "Task Manager" for Windows?

Tags: hard-drive, system-monitor

What is the window screen to reach to the hard disk usage percentage per second on Ubuntu?

In windows, I just go to task manager and under the "Tasks" tab; there is CPU, memory, "disk" and network. (I can check on that "disk" there in task manager).

On Ubuntu; I directly go to System Monitor. On System Monitor, there is CPU History, Memory and Swap History, Network History.

But I want to check my hard disk usage percentage just like on windows. Is there any possible way to do this?

( The reason to check my disk usage is to check if the hard disk is okay or not because my laptop is extremely slow. I guess there could be some damage to the hard drive. Before I install Ubuntu; I used to use Windows OS. And on Windows OS, under task manager, disk usage percentage was 100% always even though there was no program opened, even just after reboot the Windows OS. I want to check the same disk percentage on Ubuntu now, but I couldn't see this "disk percentage" menu on Ubuntu. Is there any other menu I can reach to that beside System Monitor?)

(edit*: my laptop specs are these: CPUs: 4, Vendor: GenuineItel, Model Name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @2.50GHz, Frequency:1200.256 MHz, L2 cache: 3072 KB, Memory: Memory Total: 3828 MiB, Swap total: 3974 MiB, Hard Disk: Model Family: Seagate Samsung SpinPoint M8(AF),  Capacity: 1TB, Rotation Rate: 5400rpm)

Comment: Have you tried `iostat`

Comment: You could try `baobab`. If it's not installed already install it by `sudo apt install baobab`

Comment: This should show you latest stats every 2 seconds `iostat -Nx -dc 2`

Comment: You mention that the laptop is very slow, but you fail to mention the actual specs of your laptop. Please [edit] your question and include your CPU, RAM, and disk type specs. Your disk may also be set to IDE instead of AHCI in the BIOS, which will have slower performance. If your disk is a spinning disk and not an SSD, it's also going to be slower, as laptop disks spin at a lower RPM to use less energy. It sound likely that you have little RAM, and at least in Windows, the system was constantly hitting swap.

Comment: The simple answer is probably `SYSTEM MONITOR`.

Comment: @dobey Dear Dobey; I edited and added the specs of the PC. Yes, it is a spinning disk, I know the difference of SSD and spinning disk.  Of course SSD is faster, I know.  But the problem is that: I used to use the same same spinning hard disk for 4 years, it was fast. But last week all in a sudden while copying some files, it just stuck, the computer frozen and  after that it is always very slow. After rebooting the Windows OS, it turns on and off about 20 minutes which it was maximum  3 minutes. And after turned on the operating system, I can not use it properly due to that slow.

Comment: Right, so you've only got 4GB RAM, a very old disk which has I guess seen heavy use and as you state had transfer interrupted recently. It is quite likely that under Ubuntu, your system is running into swap, which will cause slowdowns, especially when additional disk I/O is happening, beyond the swapping. I'd suggest running memtest from the grub boot screen, and also running some disk tests if possible. From your comment to the answer below, it seems your disk is indeed starting to go bad.

Answer (score 2):

> The reason to check my disk usage is to check if the hard disk is okey
>   or not, because my laptop is extremely slow. I guess there could be
>   some damage on hard disk.

If you worry about your disk, check the SMART status. `gsmartcontrol` is a nice GUI for this. Install it using `sudo apt install gsmartcontrol`.

After starting it, you'll get a list of smart parameters for your drive:

[image: gsmartcontrol]

As you can see, some indicators are termed pre-failure, others old age. The values generally progress from 100 to 1, with 100 being brand new, and 1 is worn out. The raw value may be meaningless, or provice *some* information, but the most interesting is the 'Norm-ed value' and 'Failed' column, which is likely to give you a pre-failure indicator of the drive, as well as some information on for instance wear (if it's an SSD).

If a disk is so damaged that it is noticeably slow, I think you'd see some uncorrectable read errors in there, which is a good indicator for a spinning disk.

Comment: Dear @vidarlo ; thank you for your detailed reply. I installed gsmart and tried to check with that.  I get a result like this: ![https://imgur.com/wx29jbW](https://imgur.com/wx29jbW). It seems to be everything is okay with the hard disk. On the other hand, as you can see on the screenshot, there is red  line for "current pending sector count ".  It doesn't say "failure", but since it is red color, I was worried with that. Is this something I should worry?

Comment: Nothing I'd be very worried about there. It looks over all like it's just slow; not dying. What I've seen when disks die is typically read errors and reallocated sectors go trough the roof. That said - keep a good backup...

Comment: It should be noted that your disk is a 5400RPM disk. They tend not to be fast, especially compared to SSD's which many laptops nowadays are equipped with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `htop`

`sudo apt-get install htop` to install it.

If you run it as a regular user you won't have privileges to see the Disk I/O.

If you run it with `sudo htop` and then use the menus to add I/O columns you can see what each process is doing in terms of disk activity.

In `htop`

Press`F2` > Go down to columns and then use `F5` to add the following.

`IO_READ_RATE`

`IO_WRITE_RATE`

`IO_RATE`

You will have to use `sudo` to view the I/O activity, if you run `htop` without `sudo` you will see that the I/O columns say "no perm".

Comment: NOTE: To current, Ubuntu 20.04 users, `htop` has removed the I/O capabilities. the closest I have found is `iotop`